# How can I find games by price in Steam?

Tags: steam

I want to look at Steam games in their store sorted by price (I want to see their $30 games if it matters), but I can't figure out how (other than games under $10/$5).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you go to the [search page](http://store.steampowered.com/search/) and click "advanced search", you can also filter for games under 15$, under 20$, and over 20$, in addition to the under 5$ and under 10$ categories.

Alternatively, you can just not search anything - that will display *all* games - and then sort according to price, by clicking the header of the "price" column. You can click it again to toggle between ascending or descending search.

Here's [a direct link to page 5 of the descending link](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price&sort_order=DESC&page=5) - where 30$ games start to appear - but as games are added and prices change constantly, the page in which 30$ games appear is bound to change.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I do it too.

Answer (score 12):

Check their [online search page](http://store.steampowered.com/search/). There you can filter by pre-set price ranges.

Or change the url by adding ?price=*min,max* to set your own filter.

So if you wanted everything in the $30-$40 range, go to

http://store.steampowered.com/search/?price=30,40

Comment: UHAXRWEBZ! (+1)

Comment: Unfortunately, This method is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to http://store.steampowered.com/
2. click the search icon (with nothing in the search box)
3. click 'Sort by' and select 'Lowest Price'
4. after results have refreshed go to your browser's URL bar and add '00' and hit Enter/Return key

Answer (score 0):

It appears they've eliminated this functionality for some dumb reason.
Sort by price is no longer an option.
(Necro post, but one at the top of search list)